# How to change a system::string from a combo box to a char

Tags: c++-cli

```
char    addprt_lines[2];

System::String^ numberoflines = this->comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString();

sprintf(adpt.addprt_lines, "%u", (numberoflines));
```

Hello,

I basically want the user to be able to pick a number from the comboBox which has to values 6-9 in it.

I want that selection to be then used to say what the adpt.addprt_lines value is.

So how do I make the selection a char so I can use it?

TIA

I am using c++/cli

Comment: Correct tag is C++-CLI, not command-line-interface. Generally you use `marshal_as` to go to/from C strings or C++ `std::string` into `System::String^`, but it looks like you could `Int::Parse` and then `sprintf` that.

Comment: @Amy Please write an answer and then accept the best.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to do. If you want to store combobox selected item in char, basically :

```
char addptr_line;
System::String ^numberoflines = this->comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString();

addptr_line = System::Convert::ToUInt32(numberoflines);
System::Console::WriteLine(addptr_line);
```